# Changing a view after modalViewController is dismissed (Cocoa Touch)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a viewController that presents a modalViewController when a UINavigationBarItem is touched. After the user is done with the modal view, the modalViewController is dismissed. At this point I want to change/remove the NavigationBarItem -- how would I accomplish this?

I was thinking of using viewWillAppear: but I only want the change to happen when the modalViewController is dismissed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Before presenting the modal view, call [addObserver](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver:selector:name:object:) to prepare to be notified.
At the place where the modal view is dismissed, post a notification using [postNotificationName](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName:object:userInfo:).

The notification will call a method you specify in addObserver.
In this method, put your "modal view dismissed" logic.